# API datetime-local input format invalid

Tags: javascript

I have a `datetime-local` input that defines date and time. This is supposed to be stored in backend.

Using the input I get the following string `2020-05-29T14:45`, but the API is expecting the following format `2020-05-29T14:45Z` - where does the `Z` come from and how can I add it?

Comment: `date.toISOString()`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString

Comment: `Z` is the time zone (it comes for "Zulu", which roughly stands for UTC). I don't think `<input type="datetime-local">` is even meant to provide time zone information.

Answer (score 0):

I've added the following snippet - you want to convert the input via the Date api and use the `toISOString()` method

```js
const value = document.querySelector('input').value;
const isoString = new Date(value).toISOString()

const handleInput = (e) => {
  const value = e.target.value;

  const isoString = new Date(value).toISOString()
  console.log(isoString)
  // TODO:
  // use post request to send isoString to API here:
  // can add example if given api endpoint
  return isoString;
}
```

```html
<label for="meeting-time">Choose a time for your appointment:</label>

<input type="datetime-local" 
       id="meeting-time"
       name="meeting-time" value="2018-06-12T19:30"
       min="2018-06-07T00:00" 
       max="2018-06-14T00:00"
       onchange="handleInput(event)"
       >
```